# Brain evolution in the age of the caesarian

Tags: human-biology, genetics, evolution

I have just been reading an account of the evolution of human intelligence in Matthew Syed’s recent book on diversity, called “Rebel Minds”.

He is not the originator of this idea, but he suggests that the limiting factor in the growth of the human brain beyond it’s already prodigious size is the size of the female birth canal, so that, above a certain size it had killed the mother and itself at birth.

I am not a biologist.  But I wondered whether there is any evidence of increase in brain size in the past (say) 50 years as more gravidae give birth by C-section?  Is such a change possible or probable as this procedure becomes more common?  Or are there other limiting factors, such as the weight that can be carried by the spine?

Comment: 50 years - maybe two human generations - is hardly long enough for evolution to have a measurable effect.  Also, head size is not high among the reasons why C-sections are done.  Nor AFAIK is there any fundamental reason why human brains(or other species) could not continue growing after birth.  (E.g. marsupials.)

Comment: @jamesqf Thank you.  Yes it is obvious, now you mention it, that 50 years was a ridiculously short suggestion.